# Add multiple functions to ggplot with individual x values

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot

I have the following table

```
> Test
# A tibble: 10 x 4
     Day Chemical   Amount    SE
   <int> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 Chemical 1      5     1
 2     1 Chemical 1      4     1
 3     3 Chemical 1      3     1
 4     7 Chemical 1      2     1
 5    14 Chemical 1      1     1
 6     0 Chemical 2      6     1
 7     1 Chemical 2      5     1
 8     3 Chemical 2      4     1
 9     7 Chemical 2      3     1
10    14 Chemical 2      2     1
```

So i have created a ggplot as follows

```
ggplot(Test, aes(x=Day, y=Amount, fill=Chemical)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=Chemical))
```

[Concentration of Chemical over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9cvA.png)

Then I want to display these two functions in ggplot as well.

```
a1 <- 100    
a11 <- 75

a2 <- 100 
a22 <- 80  
k1 <- 0.1 
k11 <- 0.01 

k2 <- 0.5 
k22 <- 0.01
f1 <- function(x) a1*exp(-k1*x)+a11*exp(-k11*x)
f2 <- function(x) a2*exp(-k2*x)+a22*exp(-k22*x)
```

Now heres my question: How can I tell ggplot that I want the first function (f1) to take the x values (Amount) from "Chemical 1" and the second function (f2) should take x values (Amount) from "Chemical 2"?

Comment: Why don't you use `+ stat_function(fun = f1, aes(colour = "Chemical 1"))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick solution for 2 groups (or 2 chemicals in your case). You simply subset the data, and call geom_line applying the function only in the subset, and doing it again for Chemical 2:

```
library(ggplot2)

    Test <- structure(list(Day = c(0L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 14L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 14L
    ), Chemical = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Chemical 1", "Chemical 2"), class = "factor"), 
        Amount = c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L), SE = c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))

    g <- ggplot(Test, aes(x=Day, y=Amount, fill=Chemical)) +
      geom_point(aes(shape=Chemical))

    g + 
    geom_line(data=subset(Test,Chemical=="Chemical 1"),aes(y=f1(Day),col="Chemical 1"))+
    geom_line(data=subset(Test,Chemical=="Chemical 2"),aes(y=f2(Day),col="Chemical 2"))
```

Do you have more than 2?

Comment: Works fine. Yeah its more than 2, but I got it done. Thank you!

Comment: Ok! Yeah if it's a lot better to include it in the original data.frame

Comment: Oops, sorry I saw the typo, it should be f2(Day) in the second geom_line

Comment: Hi @oliebisc, check that you used the correct function, f2 onto chemical 2 and f1 onto chemical 1, apologies for my typo..